# What the difference between pin and pn diodes i-v curve?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

For my understanding there should be no big difference in i-v curve between regular p-n junction and p-i-n junction, the only difference i can think about is do to the bigger resistance of the intrinsic layer. The curve should look the same only the current will rise little bit slower, because of the resistance.
Am i right?

Comment: In a PIN diode the voltage drops over a wider region (the deletion region) so the electric field will be lower (volts per meter). This will change the balance between drift and diffusion currents as compared to a PN structure so one might except lower knee voltage. I have the analytical equations somewhere for PN and PIN. I will try and do a proper answer later.